# Apache storm execute bolts on different machines (designated node)

Tags: python-2.7, apache-storm

I want to create a topology in which one spout is there which emits words, and a bolt which based on these words create a directory named with word.

I have two supervisor nodes on and want that if word starts with "a" to "l" the directory is created on one node and on another node otherwise.
e.g if word is 'acknowledgement' then one directory will be created on one node and if word is "machine" then directory will be created on another node.

Please suggest a way to configure storm to achieve this.

I would also like to know if one bolt is enough or if two bolts are deployed how can one manage that one bolt is run on one machine and another on other machine.

P.S. I am using Pyleus(https://github.com/Yelp/pyleus) for creating bolts and spout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single bolt but two instances of it. Each instance of this bolt runs a each supervisor node. Use custom field grouping functionality to achive the same. Your custom field grouping logic decides to which instance of the bolt this word has to dispatch.

Comment: But how can I make Bolt to execute on each node and what if one node goes down?
As soon as one goes node down storm will try to run it on other node..
Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't be sure a Bolt / Spout will be present in a specific worker (JVM). It is part of Storm design: have workers on different hardwares that are similar as Storm decides which bolt / spout instances goes to which worker.

Storm includes an abstraction: topologies are not tied to a cluster and can be rebalanced at runtime. It is wonderfully resilient and performant but you can't make specific code that run on a specific node easily (it would also be an anti-pattern in storm philosophy).

AFAIK Storm uses a mod hash function for the repartition of tasks / executors in workers (managed by supervisors), and you can't overwrite it easily.

So your best bet is to have tasks >= executors >= workers as storm will try to divide equally the load in workers of your cluster.